# Prevent property from being updated by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What's the best way to prevent my CreatedOn property from being overwritten, please see below:

```
public class MyObject
{
   ...
   public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I know that I can pass it to the view and use a hidden object, but I don't want to rely on that.

My update method looks like this:

```
var originalObject = db.Object.Find(model.objectId);

if (originalObject != null)
{
   ...
   db.Entry(originalObject).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I was trying to prevent doing a read and setting each property individually. Also, I don't have the CreatedOn method listed in the Bind list, so the value in the database is being overwritten with NULL or throwing an error that it can't be NULL, depending on the way that I have the property setup in the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use property `IsModified` to define if specific entity property was modified:

```
db.Entry(originalObject).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
db.Entry(originalObject).Property(o => o.CreatedOn).IsModified = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

When set to `false`, column will not be updated in the database.

As you can see, as you want to exclude more properties, you need to write more code. It is very easy to forget exclusion when some new properties are added as well. Therefore, I recommend using view models where appropriate. When using view model, instead of entity you are using custom object with only properties that make sense for your specific view. It is a huge topic to cover in SO answer, but you can read a [good introduction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc/) to the topic.

Comment: you have to change `context` as `db` no :)

Comment: No problem :) I also think this may be the solution +1

Comment: @dotnetom That worked perfectly, thanks. I had been searching for literally hours... I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: @Stephen Hope you can **Up Vote** the answer too.Always try to give maximum for the guy who helped to you :) here you can see how to do that : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @dotnetom I am using a view model, but I had the same challenge after I updated the actual model properties from the view model since I have to use the actual model type in SetValues. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Stephen Your view model should contain only the data you need, and since you don't want to save `CreatedOn` property, it probably should not be in the view model. If I'm not mistaken you don't need to provide the same object type to `SetValues` method, so it should work even if property is not there.